# MapBox control buttons are empty

Tags: angular, mapbox, mapbox-gl-draw, mapbox-gl-geocoder

The polygon and Trash Control Buttons for MapBox are seen empty as below (functionality works perfectly).

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dPW61.png)

```
this.draw = new MapboxDraw({
    userProperties: true,
    displayControlsDefault: false,
    controls: {
      combine_features: false,
      uncombine_features: false,
      polygon: true,
      trash: true
    }
  });
  this.map.addControl(this.draw, 'top-left');
```

Expected Output
[Expected Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nnPna.png)

Comment: Sounds like you didn't bring in the CSS for mapbox-gl-draw

Comment: Hi @chriswhong . 
I checked and I have already added the CSS link in the index.html file already.

`<!--MapBoxScript-->
  <script src='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.47.0/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
  <link href='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.47.0/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet'>
  <script src='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/plugins/mapbox-gl-draw/v1.0.4/mapbox-gl-draw.js'></script>`

Answer (score 0):

Please add this to your styles array in your angular.json and it'll work.

"styles": [
"./node_modules/mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl.css",